# BlackBerry web testing

Tags: testing, blackberry

I did a small web application for using PHP, HTML, and JavaScript.

I want to test my application in BlackBerry and iPhone, but I don't have either of them.

Is there any site providing facilities, something like a live BlackBerry tester site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have access to an iPhone simulator as a registered Apple developer.  But this is for the Mac OS X platform, not Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For Blackberry, you can download [a simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp) from RIM.  You want to download the smartphone simulator and also the MDS simulator, which enables the smartphone simulator to connect to websites.

Comment: I thing, 

For this i need the MS .net environment

Comment: i have to download this one 
Downloading BlackBerry Web Development Plug-in for Eclipse 1.0 

or which on

Comment: For my app, I used the links "Download BlackBerry smartphone simulators" and "Download the BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulator Package v4.1.4"

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the Firefox add-on, User Agent Switcher, and have it act like a Blackberry.  Granted though, it's not a true test.  But if you are looking to see how your app reacts to this, it is a good first test.